# Android SQLite: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, bind

Have has several issues trying to get the database working now I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stu54259.plan2cook/com.stu54259.plan2cook.Recipe}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

**Recipe.java**

```
package com.stu54259.plan2cook;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.RecipeList;
import com.stu54259.plan2cook.database.DatabaseManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.stu54259.plan2cook.database.DatabaseManager.*;

public class Recipe extends MainActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ImageView recipeImage;
    TextView descriptionText, courseText, servingsText, costText, caloriesText, methodText;
    RecyclerView listIngredient;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String search_name;
    Cursor c;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapterRecipe;
    List<RecipeList> itemRecipe = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
        //search_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        search_name = "Speedy chicken couscous";

        loadRecipe();
        //recyclerview Recipe
        adapterRecipe = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, itemRecipe);
        listIngredient = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        listIngredient.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        listIngredient.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listIngredient.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);

    }
    public void loadRecipe() {
        itemRecipe.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String RECIPE_SEARCH = " SELECT A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
                "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS +
                " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";

        c = db.rawQuery(RECIPE_SEARCH, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
                recipeList.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COL_ID")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY")));
                recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_NAME")));
                recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_DESCRIPTION")));
                itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Can provide more snippets if necessary but I have no idea what this means or how to resolve? Seems to be happening at this line   c = db.rawQuery(RECIPE_SEARCH, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});

**UPDATE**

Made these amendments as suggested but now get this error
Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 15 rows, 5 columns.
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

```
public void loadRecipe() {
    itemRecipe.clear();
    db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
    String RECIPE_SEARCH = " SELECT A.recipe, A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
            "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS +
            " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";
    String selectQuery = "";
    selectQuery = RECIPE_SEARCH + " WHERE A.recipe LIKE ?";
    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
            recipeList.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COL_ID")));
            recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY")));
            recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME")));
            recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_NAME")));
            recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_DESCRIPTION")));
            itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the recipe search query have a where clause with the argument you want to format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved a tweak of the toString and layout xml combined with the help offered here has fixed this issue. Thank you very much I'm sure I will have many more to come.

Answer (score 0):

Your query column names are different than the ones you're trying to retrieve using the cursor.

Also note that the cursor is case sensitive so the columns should be exactly the same as in the physical table

You should also add to the query the where clause that you need like `Where ColA like '%?%'`